# Mute current game sound with keybind, but not Steam Overlay

Tags: audio, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, volume-mixer, mute

I like to play Rainbow's Six Siege, but I also browse the internet as well as watch youtube in between. Sometimes you die early in the round and have to sit and watch cameras for 3 minutes or so, which I'd rather spend watching a youtube video. That I can easily do with Shift+Tab, to open the steam overlay, and go to youtube in the browser. The problem is that it's impossible to hear anything while the players in the background are still shooting. So, how would I mute the game with a simple keybind, without muting the overlay, and unmute the game on the next round?

I tried using SoundVolumeView to create a desktop shortcut with a keyboard shortcut bound to it that mutes the game, but for some reason windows's shortcuts always takes like 3 seconds to execute, plus I have to alt+tab out of the fullscreen game, or else the shortcut is not executed.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: By far the easiest solution is to use audio ducking aka compression. You can use Equalizer APO to do this. Once setup, just make sure the ingame volume is not on a high volume. If no other sound is playing, the volume is automatically raised. You play your Youtube video on a high volume and it automatically pushes the in-game volume to the back. You can still hear it, but only just so much, unless the video does not have any loud sounds at that moment. This is the best way because that way, you will remain attached to the game and not get caught up in the video remaining AFK after you spawned.

Comment: Thank you that sounds like the perfect solution. Will try it out now.

Comment: @LPChip I installed it and it looks very promising, except that I don't know how to use it for that purpose. Can you maybe point me to the correct place on how to set it up?

Comment: I don't know the exact steps, but you need to add a gain compresesor or audio equalization or whatever it is called, which will, based on the treshold lower/raise the volume, and use gain to set the level as you want. Then set the volumes of the game and youtube accordingly.